# Python Locking method untill finish

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, locking, sequential

I have a class python has function A and another class has function B I need run only one instance of function A even the function B called multiple times so if i have 100 client request B function they need to wait excution of A as Below

file 1

```
Class second
 def B(id):
    first.A(id)
  
 Class first
 def A(id):
    update_db_table(id+1)
```

so i need to wait A function to done to recall it again from second class

I tried Lock but doesn't work

Comment: How did you try `Lock`? Show the non-working code. Does this rule about locks apply across all instances of class `A`? You could put the lock on the class itself.

Comment: And please write actual python. That's some sort of pseudocode that leaves out important stuff.

Comment: hi @tdelaney I'm using lock but it doesn't work still run another instance of function A

Comment: You already said that in your question. I asked you to show how you are using the Lock. I have no idea what you mean by "another instance of function A". Are you calling function A multiple times in different threads?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes I'm calling function A multiple times in different threads? at same time

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all instances of class `first` want to serialize access to the database, you can put a lock on the class object. Instances of `first` don't have a variable "lock" and so fall back to the class level variable.

```
import threading

class Second:

    def __init__(self, first):
        self.first = first
        
    def B(self, id):
        self.first.A(id)
        
class First:

    db_lock = threading.Lock()
    
    def A(self, id):
        with self.db_lock:
            update_db_table(id + 1)
```

There is much unanswered in your question, like what this `update_db_table` function is. Perhaps the lock is best implemented in that bit of code.

Comment: even using lock when I Call B function from multiple clients if there is a running instance of function A start another one

Comment: "from multiple clients" ... what does that mean? You have multiple programs running? Or this is a server aggregating multiple programs calling in on some sort of an API?